# Select from database MySQL show value in input text html select by value from another input text html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi again stack overflow,
I want to show value from MySQL database and show it in the same form, is that possible?

I have html form like this:

```
<td>Barcode/td> <<-- select from database by barcode input text and show result to input text dname, three, four, five
<td><input type='text' id="barkode" name='barkode'/></td>   
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type='text' id="dname" name='dname'/></td>   
<td>three</td>
<td><input type='text' id="three" name='three' /></td>    
<td>four</td>
<td><input type='text' id="four" name='four'/></td>  
<td>five</td>
<td><input type='text' id="five" name='five' /></td>
```

any references any comment would help, thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Yes, you need to select record from database and need to set that in your each input field like <input type='text' id="dname" name='dname' value='<?php echo $data["dname"]; ?>'/>

Answer (score -1):

1.)Make a select query for the data that you require.

2.)Then echo the value in the value attribute of input field

eg.

```
$res = $con->query('Select * from barcode where `id`=1');
```

$row = $res->fetch_assoc();

```
<input type='text' id="barkode" name='barkode' value='<?php echo $row['barcode']?>'>
```

Answer (score -1):

**you have to do code like this for geting value form your database**

```
include('yourConnection');
    $sql="SELECT * FROM TabmeName WHERE id="$id";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($result) {
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
             $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);   
           $name = $row['barkode'];
    }
}
```

> inputs

```
  <td><input type='text' id="barkode" name='barkode' value="<?php echo $name ?>"/></td>
```